# uncaught at check call: argument fn is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am facing this issue while making apis calls inside redux saga. As soon, I remove these api calls, I don't get these errors but with these api calls inside my saga, I get these errors. I could not figure out as why it is happening.

the part of saga

```
          function* loginUser(action) {
           try {
             let facebookuser={};
             let isNewUserFlag = false;

             const photourl =yield call(
               getPhoto,
            action.socialData.id
          );
         const facebookuserdata=yield call(
              facebookuserdata,
             action.socialData.access_token
           );
} 
the two api calls are 


        const getPhoto= id =>
    axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${id}/picture?type=large`)
    .then((response)=>response)
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log("getphotoerror",error);
    })

          const facebookuserdata= id =>
              axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,friends&access_token=' + id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        console.log("facebookuser",json);
    })
     .catch((error) => {
     console.log("facebookuserdataerr",error);
   });
```